# Rails 4 - sum values grouped by external key

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I know this must be simple but I'm really lost.

Three models: Job, Task and Operation, as follows:

```
Job
has_many :tasks

Task
belongs_to :job
belongs_to :operation

Operation
has_many :jobs
```

`Job` has an attribute, `total_pieces`, which tells me how many pieces you need.
For each `Job`, you can add a number of `Tasks`, which can belong to different `Operations` (cutting, drilling, etc.) and for every task you can set up a number of pieces.
I don't know in advance how many `Operations` will be needed for a single `Job`, but I need to alert user of the number of pieces left for that `Operation` when a new `Task` is inserted.

Let us make an example:

```
Job 1: total_pieces=100
- Task 1: operation 1(cutting), pieces=20
- Task 2: operation 1(cutting), pieces=30
- Task 3: operation 2(drilling), pieces=20
```

I need to alert the user that they still need to cut 50 pieces and to drill 80.
Hypothetically, if i add:

```
- Task 4: operation 3(bending), pieces=20
```

I need to alert the user that they also still need to bend 80 pieces.

So far i've managed to list all kinds of `Operations` for each `Job` using `map`, but now i need to sum up all pieces of the `Task` with the same `Operation` type in a `Job`, and only for those `Operations` present in the `Tasks` belonging to that `Job`.

Is there any way to do this using `map`? Or do I need to write a query manually?

EDIT: this is what I managed to patch up at the moment.

A method `operations_applied` in Job gives me a list of ids for all the `Operations` usend in `Tasks` queued for the `Job`.
Then another method, `pieces_remaining for(operation)` gives me the remaining pieces for the single `operation`.
Finally, in the `Job` views I need, I iterate through all `operations_applied` printing all `pieces_remaining_for`.
I know this is not particularly elegant but so far it works, any ideas to improve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not misunderstanding, it is not possible to do what you want to do with `map`, since map always applies to `arr.size == arr.map {...}.size` and you want to `reduce` your array.

What you could do is something like this:

```
job = Jobs.first

operation_pieces = {}
job.tasks.each do |task|
  operation_pieces[task.operation.id] ||= { operation: task.operation }
  operation_pieces[task.operation.id][:pieces] ||= 0
  operation_pieces[task.operation.id][:pieces] += task.pieces
end
```

Now `operation_pieces` contains the sum of `pieces` for the operation with the `id` of the respective index. But I'm sure there is a more elegant version to do this ;)

EDIT: changed the code example to a hash

EDIT: and here is the more elegant version:

```
job = Jobs.first
job.tasks
    .group_by(&:operation)
    .map { |op, tasks|
      { op => tasks.sum(&:pieces) }
    }
```

The `group_by` groups your array of tasks by the operation of the task (maybe you need to use `group_by { |t| t.operation }` instead, I'm not sure) and inside the `map` afterwards the `pieces` of each task with the same operation is summed up. Finally, you end up with a hash of the type `OPERATION => PIECES_SUM (INTEGER)`.

Comment: Thank you, this is much better than my patched up solution!

Answer (score 0):

I assume the following variables required for your query,

**attributes**
Task: 
number_of_pieces,
Job:
name,
Operation:
name

```
Job.joins("LEFT JOIN tasks ON jobs.id = tasks.job_id").joins("LEFT JOIN operations ON operations.id = tasks.operation_id").select(" SUM(tasks.number_of_pieces) as number_of_pieces, operations.name, jobs.name").group("operations.id, jobs.id")
```

This will list all the jobs, and sum of pieces required for each operation under it.

if you have the job_id for you want the list of operations and the pieces, then use the below code,

```
Job.find(params[:job_id]).joins("LEFT JOIN tasks ON jobs.id = tasks.job_id").joins("LEFT JOIN operations ON operations.id = tasks.operation_id").select(" SUM(tasks.number_of_pieces) as number_of_pieces, operations.name, jobs.name").group("operations.id, jobs.id")
```

please put in comments if your need any explanation.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to avoid using SQL... see my edit for my further approach at the problem

Comment: I guess for that, you will have to refactor the structure of the database. Job and Operation has no relation between them. So achieving it without SQL queries is not possible.